# JSON Object Multiple filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

I have JSON object in which data gets filter on Selecting elements from form.
My form has following elements:

`Min Age - Max Age` and  `Gender - male(1) & female(2)`

Following is my JSON object:

```
[
   {
      "id":"1",
      "name":"nehil",
      "gender":"1",
      "birthday":"1991-07-22",
      "business_id":"1",
      "timestamp":"2016-03-23 04:46:42",
      "age":"24"
   },
   {
      "id":"2",
      "name":"vartika ",
      "gender":"2",
      "birthday":"1990-08-14",
      "business_id":"1",
      "timestamp":"2016-03-23 04:46:46",
       "age":"25"
   },
   {
      "id":"3",
      "name":"atharva",
      "gender":"1",
      "birthday":"1992-10-10",
      "business_id":"1",
      "timestamp":"2016-03-23 04:46:49",
       "age":"23"
   },
   {
      "id":"4",
      "name":"karan",
      "gender":"1",
      "birthday":"1992-12-22",
      "business_id":"1",
      "timestamp":"2016-03-23 04:46:52",
      "age":"23"
   }
]
```

On `Gender` select if male, I want `id` of all males from the object and push it in array. 
Later if I select min age as 23 and max age as 24, I want all males with following age to be updated in that array.

What will be best strategy to achieve this?

Following is my fiddle link - http://jsfiddle.net/Nehil/2ym3ffo0/4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
var arrMale,arrFeMale ; 
arrMale = geGenderData(1)
arrFemale = geGenderData(2)

console.log(arrMale)
console.log(arrFemale)

    function geGenderData(intGenderNum){

        return data.filter(function(oneObj,key){

           return oneObj.gender ==intGender;
        })

    }
```

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nehil/2ym3ffo0/3/);

Similar you can do for age with Min and Max condition

Comment: `intGender` will be `intGenderNum` in function right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an object with special structure for searching, if you need t search for more than one item. This proposal uses an object, with this structure for filtering:

```
{ 
    gender: '1',
    age: {
        min: 23, 
        max: 24
    },
    birthday: function (s) { return s.match(/-10-10/); }
}
```

The algorithm looks for every property in `search` and if *all* comparisons are true, then the element is added to the result set.

```js
function filter(array, search) {
    return array.filter(function (a) {
        return Object.keys(search).every(function (k) {
            return (
                a[k] === search[k] ||
                typeof search[k] === 'object' && +search[k].min <= a[k] &&  a[k] <= +search[k].max ||
                typeof search[k] === 'function' && search[k](a[k])
            );
        });
    });
}

var data = [{ id: "1", name: "nehil", gender: "1", birthday: "1991-07-22", business_id: "1", timestamp: "2016-03-23 04:46:42", age: "24" }, { id: "2", name: "vartika ", gender: "2", birthday: "1990-08-14", business_id: "1", timestamp: "2016-03-23 04:46:46", age: "25" }, { id: "3", name: "atharva", gender: "1", birthday: "1992-10-10", business_id: "1", timestamp: "2016-03-23 04:46:49", age: "23" }, { id: "4", name: "karan", gender: "1", birthday: "1992-12-22", business_id: "1", timestamp: "2016-03-23 04:46:52", age: "23" }];

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(filter(data, { birthday: function (s) { return s.match(/-10-10/); } }), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(filter(data, { gender: '2' }), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(filter(data, { gender: '1', age: { min: 23, max: 24 } }), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: If I want people with `birthday` today, then how can I filter birthday with today's date and month and neglecting year? eg. today's date is `10-10-2016` and I want people with birthday today like `1992-10-10`.

Comment: you can extend the object to accept a function for getting part result.

Comment: I tried to get list of people who's birthday is from `'/-04-10/'` to `'/-10-10/'` and I am getting null value. Updated Fiddle for what I tried : http://jsfiddle.net/Nehil/2ym3ffo0/5/

Comment: you need a function for birthday like this: `function (s) { return s.match(/\d{4}-(10|0[456789])-10/); }`

Comment: The above function gives only 1 data set instead of 2 and If I try giving range of 7 days I get value null. Like date from `/-07-17/` to `/-07-23/`? Can You edit the answer above? Thanks